# Error while installing Mono Droid framework platform

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to test new hardware accelerated image from Google - Android Intel Atom x86 with no luck. Emulator starts (about 30 s. which is great comparing to previous 5 minutes)
but than i get:

```
Detecting shared runtime location

Detecting package list location

Getting package list from device

Installing shared runtime package on device
484 KB/s (25872618 bytes in 52.172s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
Success

Installing the platform framework
355 KB/s (16537132 bytes in 45.442s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Failed to install the platform framework
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only x86 emulator is API level 10 (2.3.3).  It looks like your application is targeting a higher API level than this.  Your application needs to target 10 or lower.

Comment: No, my application is targeting API level 10 (2.3)

Comment: But, I checked advanced settings for Android Build and I had an empty list of supported ABI's (which means armeabi was used). After checking x86 I get package creation error: System.InvalidOperationException: Unsupported configuration: Could not load resource 'libmono-android.shared.x86-emu.so'.

Comment: The evaluation version currently does not support x86. Only the purchased version supports x86. A future version will add this.